# Variable length initializer_list

Tags: c++, default-value, initializer-list, variable-length

Is there in c++ a possibility to create a variable length initializer_list?

As Example:

```
std::list<string>  mylist { somemagic (listSize, "default") };
```

Or:

```
QList<MyClass>     anotherList { somemagic (listSize, {MyClassInitializerHere} ) };
```

Comment: Just call the constructor directly.

Comment: that does only work on classes that have a fill-contructr. QList for example does not have.

Answer (score 2):

No, `initializer_list` can only be created from a *braced-init-list* `{el1, el2, ...}`, whose length has to be a compile-time constant.

If the length is a compile-time constant, then you can construct a braced-init-list from a variadic expansion of a `std::index_sequence`; however, it is likely to be more straightforward to use the fill constructor of `std::list`:

```
std::list<string>  mylist(listSize, "default");
```

You can do the same for `QList` by exploiting the `fromStdList` constructor function:

```
QList<string>  mylist = QList<string>::fromStdList(
    std::list<string>(listSize, "default"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following: (https://ideone.com/eQstbh)

```
#include <initializer_list>

#if 1 // Not in C++11 // make_index_sequence
#include <cstdint>

template <std::size_t...> struct index_sequence {};

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct make_index_sequence : make_index_sequence<N - 1, N - 1, Is...> {};

template <std::size_t... Is>
struct make_index_sequence<0u, Is...> : index_sequence<Is...> {};

#endif // make_index_sequence

namespace detail
{
    template <std::size_t... Is, typename T>
    std::initializer_list<T> make_initializer_list(const T& t, index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        return { (static_cast<void>(Is), t)... };
    }
}


template <std::size_t N, typename T>
std::initializer_list<T> make_initializer_list(const T& t)
{
    return detail::make_initializer_list(t, make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

Comment: for this the size must be available at compile time :(

Comment: `initializer_list` require compile-time size, so my solution to contruct it.